# Group PHP array per hour (unix)

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array which has a bunch of timestamps from records from the last 24h:

```
array(402) {
  [0]=>
  int(1518465028)
  [1]=>
  int(1518465031)
  [2]=>
  int(1518465033)
  [3]=>
  int(1518465044)
  [4]=>
  int(1518465082)
  [5]=>
  int(1518465096)
  [6]=>
  int(1518465113)
```

I want these timestamps to be grouped per hour, so I get an array like this:

```
['0:00'] => 5 //meaning there were 5 timestamps between 0 am and 0:59:59 am
['1:00'] => 7 //7 between 1 am and 1:59:59 am
```

Every hour should be in the array. If there wasn't any timestamp in this hour it should just get a value 0.

I'd like to do this in PHP since I don't have access to the MySQL itself.
Anyone knows how to do this?

**Edit (question was marked as duplicate):** I think this question is different from the one mentioned in the duplicates, since I don't have access to the MySQL queries, and the time format is Unix. At least I'm not skilled enough in PHP to make it work using the mentioned duplicate.

Comment: All of your timestamps seem to be in the 1pm hour.

Comment: Correct, that's because it's sorted by timestamp and I only posted the first few of around 1000 records.

Comment: Do you have access to `Carbon`? http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/. If you do, this is a pretty easy `while()` loop. Can be done in PHP using `DateInterval`s too, but is a bit more cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of;  format to a value of `hour:00` for each timestamp and count them:

```
$result = array_count_values(
          array_map(function($v) { return date('G:00', $v); }, $array));
```

Or loop and add the index `hour:00` and increment for each one found:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $hr = date('G:00', $value);
    $result[$hr] = isset($result[$hr]) ? ++$result[$hr] : 1;
}
```

If needed you can `sort` first or `ksort` after.

Comment: Thanks! This works! `ksort`didn't work unfortunately. He sorts it like this: 0:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, ..., 19:00, 1:00, ... . Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `ksort` with `SORT_NATURAL`.  If not, use `H` instead of `G` with `date` to add a leading `0`.  Or `sort` before.